# error: class, interface or enum expected at void

Tags: java

I've been stuck on this problem for a while, I get error:

```
class, interface or enum expected
```

Any help will be appreciated? I've been stuck on this problem and my friends cant figure it out.

here is the code:

```
package com.example.vengelen.knitting;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.content.Context;    
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.EditText;

import android.widget.TextView;

import android.widget.Button;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Rectangular extends ActionBarActivity {

    EditText amount1;
    EditText amount2;
    EditText amount3;
    TextView tt;
    Button calculate;
    double w=0;
    double x=0;
    double y=0;
    double z=0;
     /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_rectangular);
        initControls();
    }
private void initControls()
{
    amount1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    amount2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    amount3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    tt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    calculate=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button9);
    calculate.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
    {public void onClick
                (View  v) { calculate();}});
    }
    EditText input;
    EditText output;
    Button one;


    private void calculate()
    {
    w=Double.parseDouble(amount3.getText().toString());
    x=Double.parseDouble(amount1.getText().toString());
    y=Double.parseDouble(amount2.getText().toString());
    z=(x+y)*(y+w);
    tt.setText(Double.toString(z));
}





}

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_rectangular);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_selector, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
         // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
         // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: @drgPP: It's a compile-time error, so I wouldn't expect a stack trace.

Comment: Basically you have an extra `}` after your `calculate` method, so `onCreate` isn't actually in a class.. Indent the code and you'll see what I mean. I think that brace originally belonged in `initControls` though... When in doubt, ask the IDE to reformat your code, and see where it goes odd. (The code around `setOnClickListener` is very oddly formatted too... and may be missing brackets.)

Comment: it looks like you have an extra closing brace before the onCreate  method

Comment: @JonSkeet, sorry, didn't see, actually op didn't specified this is compile time, or the lane on which appears

Comment: @drgPP: An error of "error: class, interface or enum expected at void" is a compile-time error.

Comment: @JonSkeet, didn't know, i tought it's about an parameter which has been passed is of wrong type :/

Comment: @drgPP: That would still be a compile-time error though...

Comment: @JonSkeet, yes you are right, thanks for corrections.

Comment: @JonSkeet how would you go at the OnClick then?

Comment: Well it's unclear because of the indentation where you *expected* `initControls` to finish - did you intend `input`, `output` and `one` to be local variables in the `initControls` method, or fields? If they're meant to be fields, I would put them at the top with the rest of the fields. Having looked again, I don't think the code around there is so much "wrong" as "insanely difficult to read because of the indentation". Readability really matters...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have unnecesarry end brace just before your method `onCreate`:

```
 }
 ^^
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

This means that compiler thinks that by that brace, your class definition has completed and then sees a new method definition which should be within another class and hence complains about the same. As a best practice, you should always format your code.